# Thin Horizontal Line dragging from Header to the rest of the page in wp

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

It has been a mess now I have just changed some CSS yesterday as

```
display: none; }
HTML, body {width: auto!important; overflow-x: hidden!important}
```

After I change this CSS there is a line appearing from the header bottom and when I am scrolling down it just keeps dragging and I can't find any solution. Can you please help?

Here is the link of my [website](https://bookeers.com/domains/)

I am also attaching the image for reference [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0caEh.png)

Comment: You need to remove this `.site-header .site-title-wrapper-after`

Comment: from where if you dont mind me asking

Comment: You can add `.site-header .site-title-wrapper-after { display: none; }` to your custom CSS.